# Group Theory Cyclic Generators Proof

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Suppose $a$ is a power of $b$, say $a=b^k$, then $b$ is equal to a power of $a$ if and only if $\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$.

I am not even sure how to really start this. I want to say something about how $b$ has order $k$ meaning it has $k$ elements. But I am not sure if this is the correct direction to be thinking or where to go from this point.

Answer (score 0):

If $b$ is equal to a power of $a$ then $b\in\langle a \rangle$. Hence, $\langle b\rangle\subset\langle a\rangle$. Since $a$ is a power of $b$ the reverse inclusion is true.
Finally,  $\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$.

If $\langle b\rangle=\langle a\rangle$, since $b\in \langle b\rangle$, $b\in \langle a\rangle$ and $b$ is a power of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Right implication. If $b=a^l$, then $\langle b\rangle=$ $\{b^m,m\in\Bbb Z\}=$ $\{a^{lm},m\in\Bbb Z\}\subseteq\langle a\rangle$. Likewise, from $a=b^k$ follows $\langle a\rangle\subseteq\langle b\rangle$. By the double inclusion, $\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$.

Left implication. If $\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$, then $\langle b\rangle\subseteq\langle a\rangle$, namely: for every $r\in\Bbb Z$, there is $s\in\Bbb Z$ such that $b^r=a^s$. In particular (take $r=1$), $b=a^{s'}$ for some $s'\in\Bbb Z$.